# Disable 'Continue' button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So I have the following fields, basically to create an account. This is just for a prototype. I was wondering how to disable the continue button and only enable the button once all fields have been completed. I have seen this can be done using jQuery and forms, but as this isn't really a form it doesn't work correctly. I understand it may be easier using  but I have to use all of the fields there as they are shown. So basically is there a way for it work with only using what I already have?

```
 <div id="form1">

           <div class="row form-row form-bg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12 form-wrapper">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-content">

                        <legend class="hd-default">Account     information</legend>


                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="first-name">Username*:  </label> 
                                        <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="password">Password*:</label><img src="help_icon.gif" title="Password must be between 8 and 15 characters, contain at least one number and one alphabetic character, and must not contain special characters." alt="Password must be between 8 and 15 characters, contain at least one number and one alphabetic character, and must not contain special characters.">
                                        <input type="text" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                   <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="password">Re-enter Password*:</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="password1" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>



                                </div>

                                <div id="form2">


                                  <div class="row form-row form-bg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12 form-wrapper">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-content">

                        <legend class="hd-default">Contact information</legend>

  <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                                            <label>Title</label>
                                             <select name="title" class="form-control">
                                                  <option value="1">Mr</option>
                                                  <option value="2">Mrs</option>
                                                 <option value="3">Miss</option>
                                                   <option value="4">Dr</option>
                                                  <option value="5">Ms</option>
                                        </select>

                                    </div>


                                </div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="first-name">First Names(s)*:</label> 
                                        <input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name(s)" required="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="password">Surname*:</label> 
                                        <input type="text" id="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname" required="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                   <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="password">Email*:</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                          <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="password">Re-enter Email*:</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="email1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>


                                </div>
  <div id="form3"
                               <form action="?" method="POST">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
  <br/>

  </form>
                               </div>
                               <input type="submit" id="continue" value="Continue" disabled="disabled" a href="address.html"/>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: You could just add the `required` HTML attribute to your input tags. Otherwise, have a look at [jQuery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin.

Comment: Required kind of works but this is more for visual purposes. So the button can't be clicked at all until the fields are completed @Aziz

Comment: loop through all the inputs in the form with jquery each and test if they are empty. if not then $("#continue").prop("disabled", false)

Comment: How exactly? @FunkDoc

Answer (score 1):

You may not have nested forms.

Once fixed, you can just check if the fields are empty or not after an input changes.

```
$('#continue').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(checkFields())
        $('#form1').find('form').submit();
    return false;
});

function checkFields() {
    $('#form1 input').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == '')
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: What would be the code for making the button active and inactive? I can't test it otherwise

Comment: Try using $("#continue").prop("disabled", true) to disable the button and $("#continue").prop("disabled", false) to enable the button again. Funk Doc also mentioned this above.

Comment: The button is still enabled regardless, doesn't seem to work. Is it because the continue button isn't in the same form? (as there is no <form>)

Comment: Literally all the code I gave in the question is the code i'm using. So it's just the button at the end, that's what I mean I don't think they are linked

Comment: @Thomas Try the code now. If it doesn't work I might need to help you via live chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108555/discussion-between-chris-and-thomas).